# React: How do I serve images dynamically added to public dir?

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, create-react-app, serve

I have a React app (via create-react-app).

I handle file uploads and place them in `/public/images/uploads` and then access via URL like `http://myapp.com/images/uploads/blah.png`. This works fine in development.

When I `npm build` and use `serve`, I cannot access dynamically created images via the URL. If I rebuild, I can then access them.

I'm obviously missing something here. Thanks

[image]

UPDATE: I did an eject on this app.
Noticed the contents my `public/images` directory are copied at build time to `build/images` and all requests to `http://app.com/images/test.png` and served from `build/images`.

Is there a way to let webpack, which I assume is responsible for this  Should I just create my images in build as well? Seems odd.

Comment: what do you mean by `serve`? How do you save the built files, ? Locally ? Server ?

Comment: Hello! Running in dev with: 'npm start server'. Running in production with 'yarn build' then 'serve -s build -p 3000 -T'

Comment: can you show your directory structure..? where is `public`, where `build` located relatively to each other ?

Comment: @Panther Added above

Comment: yes. Thats what i guessed. You need to decide on where to upload the pictures. I would upload it to a folder `relative` to root folder. So during development my root folder would be `public` and so upload folder would be `public/prod_images`. While it is served, it should be `build/prod_images`.

Comment: So this keeps, prod images and development images separate.

Comment: And if you are planning to keep images between different builds, then the upload directory should be in a common place where it is not erased between each build.

Comment: @Panther That makes sense. I can deal with that. I'm also accessing `images` from a subdomain so need them accessible via the server URL. Please post this as an answer, so I can accept.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160263/discussion-between-ty-kroll-and-panther).